# Como iterar con este tipo de array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo esto de ejemplo
[image: Texto]

Como haria para iterarlo? Es decir quiero que en el objeto 1 me salgan los resultados del primer objetos en un div, y asi con los demás. No sé si me he explicado bien.

Answer (score 1):

con un ejemplo de que quieres hacer ayudaría bastante, aquí una guía:

Con ayuda de jquery puede hacer un append, te permite inyectar texto o html a un tag.

```
<div class="contenedor">
</div>
```

Lanza la función donde la necesites

```
<script>
 tuArreglo.forEach(elemento => {
  $(".contenedor").append(`<p> texto: ${elemento.nombreAtributo}</p>`);
 });
</script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Opino que las respuestas se deberían limitar a las etiquetas, si la pregunta no indica jquery, no debería usarse.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la sugerencia, no me había percatado

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un método similar al que muestra "*phades almaguer*" simplemente añado más información de como iterar sobre la estructura.

1. Para iterar sobre el array de Jsons utiliza el método:

   array.forEach(function(e){});
2. Para iterar sobre un objeto Json puedes utilizar:

   Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k){});

Donde "k" será el KEY y puedes buscarlo por e[key] donde "e" es el objeto json

```js
array = []
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    json = {}
    json["Key1"]="Valor1";
    json["Key2"]="Valor2";
    json["Key3"]="Valor3";
    array.push(json)
}
console.log(array);

array.forEach(function(e){
    var div= document.createElement("div");
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k){
        var p= document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText= k +" "+ e[k];
        div.appendChild(p);
    });
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que es un array de objetos, que tiene otros objetos dentro.

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   const obj = array[i];
   const size = Object.keys(obj).length;
   // Aqui podrias abrir un div (Para todos los elementos del obj)
   for(let key = 0; key < size; key++){
       console.log(`Elemento: ${i}`, obj);
       console.log(`Clave: ${key}`, obj[key])
   }
   // Aqui podrias cerrar tu div
}
```

Donde obj es cada elemento del array.
Y Clave se itera por cada objeto en orden.

*Por favor, amplia tu pregunta y danos un ejemplo reproducible. Evita ser calificado como negativo por no saber como preguntar!!!*